# How can I import a different version of a python module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, python-module

I need to run my python script under sklearn v0.17 and on the server they have sklearn v0.15 installed.

So I downloaded the `scikit-learn-0.17` package into `/home/mydir/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and installed the package.

However when I goto other directories and tried to run python and `import sklearn` the version is still 0.15.

I created `~/.startup.py` and put the following code

```
import sys  
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/mydir/lib/Python2.7/site-packages/")
```

then I pointed to `~/.startup.py` in `~/.bashrc` with

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.startup.py
```

But it does not help.

I am wondering how to fix this. Thank you!

The following files/dirs are in `site-packages/`

```
easy-install.pth              scikit-learn-0.17         site.pyc
pysam-0.9.1.4                 scikit_learn-0.17-py2.7.egg-info  site.pyo
pysam-0.9.1.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg  site.py               sklearn
```

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your site-packages folder?

Comment: @crey4fun I have added them in the question.

Comment: Can you uninstall scikit-learn again and then execute this line of code: `pip install -U scikit-learn`

Comment: @crey4fun just tried that and it raises an error saying `Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.15.2`

Comment: This is not an error. It should also say something like `uninstalling old version...`. If it does, check the scikit-learn version again and it should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Python Virtual Environments were made to fix this problem. Create a virtual environment by navigating to the directory of your project and enter the `pyvenv ./Env` command. Activate the environment on a linux system with `source ./Env/bin/activate`. Now you have a sandboxed python environment, whatever package you install now will only be scoped to this environment. So you can `pip install scikit-learn-0.17` you will only point to *THAT* package. All other packages that are not in this virtual environment are ignored unless you explicitly add them via methods like `pip`.

There are many other benefits to virtual environment, high reccomend reading more about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Answer (score 0):

General advice here would be to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), it allows you to have isolated environments for all your python projects.

So each of your project can use different scikit version.

Tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/virtual-environments-python-made-easy/